# TypeError: find_one_and_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update'

Tags: pymongo

I need help, Not sure what im doing wrong. I keep getting this error and im not sure why can anyone give me any advice:

```
TypeError: find_one_and_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update'
```

Here is my Test Code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import ReturnDocument
import datetime
from animalsCRUD import AnimalShelter

#username = "aacuser"
#password = "password"

insertRec = AnimalShelter("aacuser", "password")
locateRec = AnimalShelter("aacuser", "password")
updateRec = AnimalShelter("aacuser", "password")
deleteRec = AnimalShelter("aacuser", "password")

animal = ({"age_upon_outcome":"5 years", "animal_id":"A333333", "animal_type":"Dog", 
"breed":"Derp", "color":"White",
"date_of_birth":"07/19/19", "datetime": datetime.datetime.now(), "name":"", 
"outcome_subtype":"Foster",
"outcome_type":"Adoption", "sex_upon_outcome":"Intact Female", "location_lat":30.60784677,
"location_long":-97.35087807, "age_upon_outcome_in_weeks":64.24642857})

critter = {"animal_id":"A333333"}

changeCritter = ({"animal_id": "A333333"}, {'$set': {'animal_type': 'Cat'}})

print(insertRec.create(animal))


locateRec.locate(critter)

updateRec.update(changeCritter)

locateRec.locate(critter)

deleteRec.delete(critter)
```

Answer (score 0):

The update method has two parameters, you could decomposite the tuple

```
updateRec.update(changeCritter[0],changeCritter[1])
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I keep getting this error now: TypeError: update() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @BrandonWomack Sorry. Just use my last edit.

Comment: True
    <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7f0f1c0f04e0>
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-17-4468f58ea34f> in <module>
           25 locateRec.locate(critter)
           26 
    ---> 27 updateRec.update(changeCritter[0], changeCritter[1])
           28 
           29 locateRec.locate(critter)

     TypeError: update() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: that is the error thjat comes up now so im really confused  even when i add a 3rd it gives me: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @BrandonWomack what is the animalsCRUD library?

Comment: its a pymongo program with CRUD functionality that accesses a database of over 10000 animals mostly dogs with multiple criteria attached such as name breed color, etc.

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace and we would also need to see the AnimalShelter class code.

Comment: all needed info is found on this link: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/need-help-sure-im-wrong-keep-getting-error-true-typeerror-traceback-recent-call-last-26-lo-q66294301?trackid=bd6H56Co